# How to add labels to multiple vertical bar series?

Tags: reactjs, bar-chart, axis-labels, react-vis

Label series need x and y values to show labels. I am trying to add labels at plot that has multiple vertical bar series that has same xAxis values. The XYPlot shows labels at same vertical line if the x values are same. I used xOffset to show second labels where I want but xOffset is not stabil. How can I show labels with multiple vertical bar series correctly?[image]